# Bulk update relationships to household members

Tags: civimember

We have household memberships. Ive noticed that some households are missing a relation to a residential community that they reside in. This community is common to those households. I tried to select all those contacts and use a profile to batch update but it wont let me make a profile for relationships to households?

Is there a way to do this.

Ie:

Mary Smith
Jane Doe
Trevor ward
Leon Jones

they all live at Smithtown Residential Resort (this is a relationship called residential community)

I want to select the records then tell Civi all these household contacts belong to the residential community

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Batch Update for this - you can use the search action "Add relationship - to household".  Note that this is the 4.7 language - 4.6 probably calls it something like "Add relationship to household".
[image]

Comment: That dosnt actually work. If you click on add relationship to household after selecting the contacts it says Relationship type, so i choose Residential Community and the next field is set to Find Target Household. It dosnt show Find Target Residential Community.

Comment: so you mean it isn't working for Contact SubTypes?

Comment: After selecting the contacts, i choose Actions, followed by add relationship to household, it then says relationship type and the options are Residential Community, head of Household for or Household member of, then the final field says Find target Household

Comment: I just tested on Demo. Yes I agree it says "find target household' but does that stop you? On demo i was able to go ahead and use that to create relationships of type 'subhouse' with my target 'household'. is this just a labelling issue? This contact has 2 relationships created as JonG described http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=206

Comment: Thanks  I think you are missing my issue. We already have 500 residential communities already each one has a name.eg Oaklands Estate.When we try to use the method you described to add this Residential Community relationship to multiple contacts it asks for the Relationship type, we set to Residential Communitythen in the Find Target Household box we type in a Residential Community like Oaklands Estate it returns a household not found message. I assume that it is looking for a household rather than a organisation that is a residential community.I suspect it is something we will need coded.

Comment: @GaryMartin I don't think we can help you without more information.  Could you please explain what a "Residential Community" is in your database?  That's not a built-in contact type.  Earlier, it sounded like it was a contact subtype of "Household"; now it sounds like a contact subtype of "Organization".  Could you provide a screenshot if you're not sure of the language to use?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at an extension we developed called [householdmerge](https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.householdmerge). I am not sure if it actually solves your problem and it is still in a beta phase but it may be worth a shot.